Flutter - copy files on build
I am making a desktop Flutter application for Windows and Linux. How do I copy some config files to the top level of my build output directory on the flutter build command?
I've already tried googling.
Yes, I have seen this post: Add files to build directory in Flutter, but that is not what I want. I don't want it included in the assets. It has to be beside the launching executable.
